# Map Response to Predictable Object

Tags: javascript

I want to be able to map my fetch-response to a somewhat predictable response type but i'm not sure how to do it. if the key exists, i want to map the response value to it.

I'm fine with a field not necessarily existing in the response.
I just want to map the fields that can be mapped by key to value.

If you've used TypeScript, what I'm looking for is essentially equal to

```
const article: ArticleResponseBody = fetch(``)
//           ^ this right here   ^
// Now when I do article. 
//                      ^  I get statically evaluated autocompletion.
```

code:

```
articleResponseBody = (response) => {
    return [
      {
        accessRestriction,
        title,
        image: {
          url,
        },
        publicationTime,
        sectionPath,
        readingTime,
        vignette,
        text,
      },
    ].map({response});
}


const articleData = await fetch(`${endpoint}/v2/articles`)
                   .then(resp => resp.json())
                   .then(data => console.log(data));
const article = articleResponseBody(articleData);
// and now I can do:
article.
//     ^ autocompletion
```

data that's outputted by endpoint will share some of the keys in the articleResponseBody. i.e.

```
[
  {
    accessRestriction: "none",
    bylines: "",
    layout: "standard",
    title: "test",
    image: {
      author: "dtest",
      captionHtml: "dtest",
      width: 974,
      height: 548,
      id: "",
      imageType: "",
      type: "image",
      url:  "://"
    },
    publicationTime: "2021-03-24T15:05:47.765+01:00",
    sectionPath: "test0",
    targetLink: {
      url: "://"
    },
    readingTime: "",
    id: "test",
    vignette: "",
    text: "",
    tags: "",
    updateTime: null
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe you want to do something like `return response.map(obj => ({accessRestriction: obj. accessRestriction, etc.... }))`?

Comment: @NickParsons well, essentially I guess. But, It'd be preferable if I didn't have to type out the assignment, but instead assign through implicit object destruction. In TypeScript, you can just do `const response: ArticleResponse` and I'll get what I want, but since that is not an option, I have to go about doing this in a different way.

Comment: You can use destructuring to make it more concise, I've added an answer to show how that can be used

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Rest_in_Object_Destructuring) to pull out the properties you want to keep/discard from your object and nested objects, and then use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax) (`...`) to build your new object using the properties you want to keep:

```js
const articleResponseBody = (response) => {
    const [{
      id, // keys to remove
      tags, 
      updateTime, 
      image: {url} = {}, // keys to keep
      ...rest // all other object properties not listed above
    } = {}] = response; 
    return {...rest, image: {url}};
}

const articleData = [ { accessRestriction: "none", bylines: "", layout: "standard", title: "test", image: { author: "dtest", captionHtml: "dtest", width: 974, height: 548, id: "", imageType: "", type: "image", url:  "://" }, publicationTime: "2021-03-24T15:05:47.765+01:00", sectionPath: "test0", targetLink: { url: "://" }, readingTime: "", id: "test", vignette: "", text: "", tags: "", updateTime: null } ]
console.log(articleResponseBody(articleData));
```

If needed, you can destructure the object in a call to `.map()`, which will map all objects in your response array to the given format:

```js
const articleResponseBody = response =>
  response.map(({ id, tags, updateTime, image: {url}, ...rest }) => ({...rest, image: {url}}));

const articleData = [ { accessRestriction: "none", bylines: "", layout: "standard", title: "test", image: { author: "dtest", captionHtml: "dtest", width: 974, height: 548, id: "", imageType: "", type: "image", url:  "://" }, publicationTime: "2021-03-24T15:05:47.765+01:00", sectionPath: "test0", targetLink: { url: "://" }, readingTime: "", id: "test", vignette: "", text: "", tags: "", updateTime: null } ]
console.log(articleResponseBody(articleData));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I only want to keep the fields that are in the const { id, title, etc }. Also it isn't giving me any intellisense when i do `article.`. Not sure how to statically infer that these props will exist.

Comment: Its kinda hard to explain, but essentially, i want typescript's `type` functionality. I.e. `const article: ArticleResponse = await fetch(...)`

Comment: Hm, I haven't really needed to configure intellisense before , so I'm not too sure about that part. _Perhaps_ look at adding a jsdoc comment above your function... https://jsdoc.app/

Comment: I mean, it should be statically inferred that the returned object will have those keys. I.e. `const example = {a:1, b:2 };`. If I then do `example.` i will see `a` and `b`.

Comment: Yeah, I would have guessed that it should work in a similar way to your example. When I try it in codesandbox, it's able to infer all potential properties (so those excluded such as `id` still apear). Using JSDoc, you can make things clearer: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnTr1.png